# Magento 2: How to get column total in custom admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom

This is my custom admin grid.

[image]

The last column shows the total which is a multiplication of cost and qty fields. I want to show total of the column(total) in the last row and last column.

The row total is rendered through this function:

```
class Total extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{    /**
     * Renders grid column
     *
     * @param   Varien_Object $row
     * @return  string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
        $total_revenue_amount = 0;
        $total_qty = $row->getData("total_qty");
        $price = $row->getData("cost");
        // if(!empty($total_qty) && !empty($price)){
        //     $total_revenue_amount = $total_qty*$price;
        // }
        
        if(count($row->getData()) > 4){
            if(!empty($total_qty) && !empty($price)){
                $total_revenue_amount = $total_qty*$price;
            }
        }else{
            $total_revenue_amount = $row->getData('total_revenue_amount');
        }
        return $priceHelper->currency($total_revenue_amount, true, false);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. I hope this can help you.

Find the row in your ui component js file where is write the item tag with name "component":

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

and change it like:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_YourModule/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

The path of that js file is:

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js